# What does 妙に調子もいいし mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english, conversations

3 characters talking with each other after being transferred into a strange world:

> C1: そっちで勝手に話を進めないでほしいものね。こちらは訳も分からないまま巻き込まれた形なのだけれど？ (I want you to stop doing things arbitrarily. Even I've been involved in this for no reason too you know?)
>
> C2: いやだってあんなところで突っ立ってるから (No, it's because you were just standing there, it's not our fault)
>
> C3: ぼさっと突っ立ってる方が悪い (It's your mistake for standing there in a daze)
>
> C1: ...どうやら斬るべき敵はまだ残っていたようね。 (Looks like there are still some enemies left for me to kill here)
>
> **妙に調子もいいし**、今なら二人まとめて輪切りにしてあげられるわよ?

I don't understand the last sentence, especially **妙に調子もいいし** here. Please help me interpret this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 妙に: "strangely", "oddly", "weirdly"
- 調子がいい: "in good condition"
- も: ("among other reasons")
- し: nonexhaustive reason marker

So C1 is saying she is feeling stronger/better than usual but she does not know why. Since this is an *isekai* story, this 妙に is may be a foreshadowing. Maybe this world is giving her power, for example.